# perl6 Need help to understand more about proto regex/token/rule

Tags: regex, raku, proto

The following code is taken from  [the Perl 6 documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/language/grammar_tutorial#Keeping_grammars_with_actions_tidy_with_make_and_made), and I am trying to learn more about it before more experimentation:

```perl6
proto token command {*}
      token command:sym<create>   { <sym> }
      token command:sym<retrieve> { <sym> }
      token command:sym<update>   { <sym> }
      token command:sym<delete>   { <sym> }
```

1. Is the `*` in the first line a whatever-star? Can it be something else, such as

   ```perl6
   proto token command { /give me an apple/ }
   ```
2. Can "sym" be something else, such as

   ```perl6
   command:eat<apple> { <eat> } ?
   ```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`{*}` tells the runtime to call the correct candidate.
Rather than force you to write `{{*}}` for the common case of just call the correct one, the compiler allows you to shorten it to just `{*}`

That is the case for all `proto` routines like `sub`, `method`, `regex`, `token`, and `rule`.

In the case of the `regex` proto routines, only a bare `{*}` is allowed.
The main reason is probably because no-one has really come up with a good way to make it work sensibly in the regex sub-language.

So here is an example of a `proto sub` that does some things that are common to all of the candidates.

```perl6
#! /usr/bin/env perl6
use v6.c;
for @*ARGS { $_ = '--stdin' when '-' }

# find out the number of bytes
proto sub MAIN (|) {
  try {
    # {*} calls the correct multi
    # then we get the number of elems from its result
    # and try to say it
    say {*}.elems #            <-------------
  }
  # if {*} returns a Failure note the error message to $*ERR
  or note $!.message;
}

#| the number of bytes on the clipboard
multi sub MAIN () {
  xclip
}

#| the number of bytes in a file
multi sub MAIN ( Str $filename ){
  $filename.IO.slurp(:!chomp,:bin)
}

#| the number of bytes from stdin
multi sub MAIN ( Bool :stdin($)! ){
  $*IN.slurp-rest(:bin)
}

sub xclip () {
  run( «xclip -o», :out )
  .out.slurp-rest( :bin, :close );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This answers your second question. Yes, it's late.
You have to distinguish two different `sym`s (or `eat`s). The one that's on the definition of the token as an "adverb" (or extended syntax identifier, whatever you want to call it), and the one that's on the token itself.

If you use `<eat>` in the token body, Perl 6 will simply not find it. You will get an error like

```
No such method 'eat' for invocant of type 'Foo'
```

Where `Foo` would be the name of the grammar. [`<sym>` is a predefined token](https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/sym), which matches the value of the adverb (or pair value) in the token.

You could, in principle, use the extended syntax to define a multi token (or rule, or regex). However, if you try to define it in this way, you will get a different error:

```
Can only use <sym> token in a proto regex
```

So, the answer to your second question is no, and no.

Comment: Thank you very much jjmerelo for your help !!